# How can I access local storage to get token from cognito?

Tags: amazon-cognito, server-side-rendering, nuxt.js

I am using Nuxtjs and AWSCognito to auth user. I am saving the tokens in the local storage, however, I lost them when I refresh the page because is SSR app. How can I keep user auth after refreshing the page? Should I use Cookies? Someone could provide an example or explanation?

```
 async LOGIN({
    commit
  }, {
    username,
    password
  }) {
    try {
      let email = await this.cognito.login(username, password);
      debugger;
      Cookie.set("api_token", email.idToken.jwtToken);
      localStorage.setItem("api_token", email.idToken.jwtToken);
      localStorage.setItem("user_token", email.accessToken.jwtToken);
      commit("SET_USER", email);
    } catch (error) {
      throw (new Error(error), {
        message: error.message
      });
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [AWS Javascript SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-javascript-examples.html). When you authenticate a user, the SDK puts the tokens in local storage for you, and also handles refreshing them. Basically you shouldn't be writing any code yourself to deal with the tokens. Just work with the SDK interface.

Comment: I tried to do it, however, I am using static web site using Nuxt js. There is no way to access local storage.

Comment: I am using a static website. How can I take a cookie or do something else to authenticate a user?

Answer (score 1):

check out AWS Amplify Auth, it makes everything so easy for authentication.see here [AWS Amplify Auth](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication)